# MYSQL query that will arrange the user based on recent message in a chat app

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to build a chat application and I just want to list the full names of user based on who recently message or who I recently message. Unfortunately I can't figure out the proper SQL query to do this.

The two tables is structured liked this:

*useraccounts*

- user_id
- full_name
- email
- username
- password

*chat_message*

- chat_message_id
- to_user_id
- from_user_id
- chat_message
- timestamp
- status

If you would like to see the table with sample datas, click below

[useraccounts table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QzLB.png)

[chat_message table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EelG0.png)

Thanks in advance if you could help me with this.

Comment: [**Please Never** post images of code, data or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. 
This is so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Answer (score 0):

As you say "who recently message" I understand that it is the users who sent the latest messages that you want to see. The following query will return the last 10 users to send messages.
The last line `LIMIT 10` can be modified or removed as needed.

```
SELECT 
  u.user_id,
  u.full_name,
  MAX(timestamp) date_latest
FROM useraccounts u
JOIN chat_message c
ON u.user_id = c.from_user_id
GROUP BY 
  u.user_id,
  u.full_name
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT 10;
```